# Google Maps API: Mutiple Marker/Closures

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hey first time posting here. Trying to post multiple markers that I am pulling in from an API. I am a novice programmer, but I believe closures in the issue. I have tried many variations but I still can't get it to work. Can someone take a look?

```
$data =  json_decode($json);

//var_dump($data);


foreach($data as $object):?>


<?php endforeach;


?>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCGLTlvxWSV6x4yH5XqqItlgHHIPt8GYp0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


    var lat =  '<?php echo $object->{'latitude'}?>';

    var long =  '<?php echo $object->{'longitude'}?>';


    // check DOM Ready
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // execute
        (function() {
            // map options
            var options = {
                zoom: 5,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.909736, -98.522109), // centered US
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
                mapTypeControl: false
            };

            // init map
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), options);

            // set multiple marker
           for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                // init markers
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
                 map: map,
                 title: 'Check-In ' + i
             });

                // process multiple info windows
               (function(marker, i) {
                    // add click event
                 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                           content: '<?php echo $object->{'username'}?>'
                      });
                       infowindow.open(map, marker);
                   });
                })(marker, i);
          };
       })();

 });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 800px; height:500px;"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a world of hurt if you intersperse PHP loops with JavaScript loops like this. What you should do instead is generate a JSON array or JavaScript object for your markers from PHP, and then loop through your array in JavaScript.

For example, you could generate this JavaScript array from PHP:

```
var places = [
    { lat:10, lng:20, username:"Weez" },
    { lat:30, lng:40, username:"Mike" }
];
```

You can see where you could use your `foreach` loop to generate this, or use PHP's `json_encode` function.

Then your JavaScript code might look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng( 39.909736, -98.522109 ),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
        mapTypeControl: false
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        options
    );

    places.forEach( function( place, index ) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng( place.lat, place.lng ),
            map: map,
            title: 'Check-In ' + index
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: place.username
            });
            infowindow.open( map, marker );
        });
    });
});
```

I took out a couple of nested inline functions that aren't necessary. You are right that you need a closure (or some other mechanism) to capture the `username` for each of your markers to use in the `click` event handler, but the the callback function used with the `.forEach()` loop provides that closure for you. `place`, `index`, and `marker` are unique variables for each iteration of the loop, because they are arguments or local variables in the callback. So when you use `place.username` inside the `click` handler it has the value you expect.